# The method setValue(String) in the type OptionTag is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I have the below code in my JSP. The problem is while i run this code, i get the below exception:

```
The method setValue(String) in the type OptionTag is not applicable for the arguments (Object).
```

Does anyone have an idea?

```
<html:select property="selectedServices" name="specificStoreForm" multiple="true" styleClass="services">
  <logic:iterate id="service" name="services" property="selectedServices">
  <bean:define id="textVal" name="service" property="value" toScope="request"/>
  <html:option value="<%=textVal%>">
    <bean:write name="service" property="label"/>
  </html:option>
  </logic:iterate>
</html:select>
```

Comment: The exception occurred because i added the code change like <html:option value="<%=textVal%>">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the [documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-bean.html#define) the result from the `<bean:define>` tag is of type `Object` if you don't specify a `value` attribute. The `<html:option>` tag only works if the passed value is of type `String`.

Use EL (Expression Language) to get the value instead:

```
<html:option value="${textVal}">
    ...
</html>
```

You could also just use the [`<html:optionsCollection>`](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#optionsCollection) tag and not have to explicitly iterate:

```
<html:select property="selectedServices" name="specificStoreForm" multiple="true" styleClass="services">
    <html:optionsCollection name="services" property="selectedServices" value="value" label="label"/>
</html:select>
```

Comment: Hi anthony, I tried both the solutions. But am not getting any exceptions, instead it is forwarding to default error page

Comment: @user3392877 And? Sounds like there should be a second part to that. Did either of them work? If not, what did happen and why wasn't it what you expected?

Comment: I am not seeing any exceptions, as it seems the value required for both the implementations are not coming. and so it is forwarding to default error page

Comment: @user3392877 What do you mean by "default error page"? What's displayed on that page?

Comment: It is application oriented error page. The usual forward=error page. In our application the error page is : Session timed out message

Comment: <html:select property="selectedServices" name="specificStoreForm" multiple="true" styleClass="services">
        <logic:iterate id="service" name="services">
         <html:option value="${service.value}">          
          <bean:write name="service" property="label"/>
         </html:option>
        </logic:iterate>        
       </html:select>

Now It is working well and good..